# Swift string literal - remove escaping back slashes

Tags: swift, string, string-literals

I am in a situation where backend generates hash value of the string it's passing to the app, and there's no control over that hash value generation on backend. I need to generate same string to pass it to app's hash verification algorithm, and here's the problem:
the string that is being passed for verification needs to look like this:

```
[{"crawlLogic":{"startURL":"https://somesite.com/start","someParam":"\r\n\r\n/** Retrieves element's text either by class name" ....
```

The issue here is that string that is being verified needs to conform to 2 conditions:

**1.** no backslashes escaping double quotes (as in `[{\"crawlLogic\":{\"startURL\":\"https://somesite.com/start\"`)

**2.** has new line and tab with escapes in it without actually turning those into tabs and new lines.

When I set breakpoint and check the string literal, I see of course those backslashes. But when I print a string in console I see the `\n` turned into new lines.
I assume it takes string literal as actual value for verifiation, and therefore my question is how to remove those backslashes in the string literal?

Why or how I know this? Because in Android just before passing in string I do see this string.

**Where the string is coming from**
it's a JSON custom encoder, the string encoding looks like this:

```
private func encode(_ value: JSON, depth: Int) throws -> String {
    switch value {
    case let .string(string):
        let zeString = #""\#(string)""#
        return zeString
    case let .number(digits): return digits
    case let .bool(value): return value ? "true" : "false"
    case let .object(object): return try encode(object: object, depth: depth)
    case let .array(array): return try encode(array: array, depth: depth)
    case .null: return "null"
    }
}
```

With this I am able to get rid of backslashes in the printed string, but how to keep the \n \r in there?

Comment: Can you show where this string is coming from which contains all these backslashes? If you print out an **optional** string with quotes, you can see the ``\`` escapes. However if you unwrap it, you won't have the backslashes.

Comment: thanks, I edited the question. pls check images.

Comment: You should include code, rather than images. Anyway, you shouldn't have to deal with replacing the characters like that. You want your JSON string on client & back-end to not have ``\``s if possible

Comment: the thing is they don't. I actually got it now with quotes but no backslashes like this: `let zeString = #""\#(string)""#`

Comment: So you just needed to remove the use of the `escaped` method? Because that string looks identical

Comment: You also probably don't want characters like `\n` and stuff in there. You can always format the JSON if you need to

Comment: the problem is I can't. Whatever backend gives me - I need to make it work (pressure is also because Android is able to do it)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be confusing how the IDE displays strings and the actual strings that would be printed. Setting breakpoints and looking at the debugger will show you C-escaped strings. If you print those values, the escaping will be gone. For example, if I create the literal string you're describing:

```
let string = #"[{"crawlLogic":{"startURL":"https://somesite.com/start","someParam":"\r\n\r\n/** Retrieves element's text either by class name""#
```

The debugger will print this value's `debugDescription` which will include escaping (such as `\"` and `\\r`, note the double-backslash):

```
print(string.debugDescription)
"[{\"crawlLogic\":{\"startURL\":\"https://somesite.com/start\",\"someParam\":\"\\r\\n\\r\\n/** Retrieves element\'s text either by class name\""
```

But those extra escapes aren't actually in the string:

```
print(string)
[{"crawlLogic":{"startURL":"https://somesite.com/start","someParam":"\r\n\r\n/** Retrieves element's text either by class name"
```

If the `debugDescription` has `\r` rather than `\\r`, then that's indicating you have a carriage return (UTF-8: 0x0d) in your string, not `\r` (UTF-8: 0x5c 0x72). If you need to convert carriage return + newline into `\r\n`, then you can do that with with `replaceOccurrences(of:with:)`.

```
string.replaceOccurrences(of: "\r\n", with: #"\r\n"#)
```

This says to replace the string "carriage return, newline" with "backslash r backslash n."

(But I would first investigate why the string is in the wrong form to start with. I'm guessing you're constructing it with `"\r\n"` at some point when you meant `#"\r\n"#` or `"\\r\\n"`. Or perhaps you're unescaping a string you were given when you shouldn't. Escaping and unescaping strings is very tricky. Try to build the string to hold the characters you want in the first place rather than trying to fix it later.)

If you continue to have trouble, I recommend converting your string into UTF-8 (`Array(string.utf8)`) and looking at the actual bytes. This will remove all ambiguity about what is in the string.

Comment: thanks Rob, also for your custom parser btw, it seems the issue is even different: the set of objects is defined but we didn't know it's not just all objects, some of them are excluded and that creates the difference in hash.